BitCore Implementation For Support To community
Hello To  Bitcoin Family,
I am Bhavin Patel from India. I wanted to implement a Full Bit Core node to support the Bitcoin community. This node will be hosted on the cloud and will be available to the community for use in Bitcoin processes.
While reviewing resources and articles on Bitcore implementation and tech details, it was advised to seek ideas and tech information from respected community members on 1. security advice, 2. security implementation, 3. do's and don'ts about implementation, 4. server specification, and 5. Are there any other guidelines that will help implement and make robots secure Bitcore on the cloud?
I am a tech guy, so I can understand all aspects of implementation, security, hardware, software, etc. As a tech enthusiast and supporter of cryptocurrencies, I want to do this to support the community.
I will bear the cost of implementation operations and ongoing maintenance.
So, I request all family members of the Bitcoin community to please advise on the above points.
Thanks in advance to all my Bitcoin family members.
Regards,
Bhavin Patel

You tagged your question with both "bitcoin core" and "bitcore"  - which one are you using? Also, your question is very general, this website works best when you have one specific question. Could you edit the question to focus on one narrow specific point that is causing you most concern or difficulty?

Could you please clarify whether you are talking about setting up an instance of a full node or looking to create a new implementation of a full node?
